# Смысл выражения "воздержаться от вмешательства"

Tags: значение-слов, смысл

Объясните, пожалуйста, простыми словами эту фразу:

"Воздерживаетесь ли Вы от вмешательства, если заранее известно, что оно ни к чему не приведёт?"

Comment: Такие вопросы нужно задавать на сайте http://russian.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2):

Воздержаться = отказаться, удержать себя

= Откажетесь  ли Вы от вмешательства, если заранее известно, что оно ни к чему не приведёт?

= Будете ли Вы вмешиваться во что-то, если знаете, что изменить ничего не сможете (что результата не будет)?

Answer (score 1):

Считаете ли вы возможным отказаться от вмешательства в какое-либо дело, если заранее знаете, что ничего не сможете изменить.